# Expand Table Size R

Tags: r, matrix, scale, dimensions

I'm using `table()` and based off my binned data, it creates rows from 9 to 25 and columns from 4 to 25.

I want to compare to another table, so I need it to be 1 to 25 on each axis.

I've tried making an empty matrix that's 25x25 to add the table to, but of course that doesn't work since they don't match in size.

I'm sure there's a simple solution I've overlooked, would appreciate any help!

Comment: You 'll need to turn each argument of `table` to a `factor` with the appropriate (here, `1:25`) "levels".

Comment: Thanks alexis_laz!